# How to avoid function calling again and again

Tags: php

I created a function called remove_role which used to remove permission based on the role.  I can able to achieve by calling function again and again. Is there any other way  to avoid calling function repeatedly ?

````
    remove_role('author', 'edit_others_pages');
    remove_role('author', 'upload_files');
    remove_role('author', 'manage_categories');```
````

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can put all the roles in an array like this and call them in a loop. I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve but i think using array will be the easiest.

```
$roles = ['role1', 'role2', 'role3'];

foreach ($roles in $role) {
   remove_role('author', $role);
}
```

In fact you could also use a `hash` like `$roles = ['author' => 'role1', 'somethng else' => 'role2']` and loop that through as well.

Answer (score 0):

It all very much depends on what is in your remove_role function but one approach would be to use an array and then loop through it in your function e.g.

```
$protectedPages = ['edit_other_pages','upload_files','manage_categories']
remove_role('author', $protectedPages);

public function remove_role($role, $pages) {

     foreach($pages as $page) {
        // Do what you need to do here
    }
}
```